# Yii sorting in model via certain values

Tags: php, sql-server, sorting, yii, models

I have a CGridView with a table tblDetails .
I need to sort the table's data not by asc or desc, but by values.
the column to sort is status

column values:
1) New
2) Pending
3) Awaiting approval
4) Open
5) Approved/Closed

So I need the data sorted as in this way :

New data
open data
pending data
and so forth.

So not by asc desc.
And I cannot change the table to accommodate that because that would be cheating.

I would preferably like to do this in the model in search function but if there is a better way please mention it.

Comment: The normal way for such a problem would be to add a 'sort' field (int) to your database so you can use `sort` on that field instead of id or name. You cannot do this in the model that easily.

Comment: that is what i am trying to avoid you see. because i build completely generic sites. so anything can be changed at any one time including tables. and therefor my dev has to accomodate that without me needing to change the DB. But that is a good solution though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do such thing you need SQL statement  like this.

```
SELECT status FROM table_name 
    ORDER BY CASE name 
        WHEN 'New data' THEN 1 
        WHEN 'open data' THEN 2 
        WHEN 'pending data' THEN 3 
    END;
```

in Yii model:

```
$criteria = new CdbCriteria();
$criteria->order ="CASE Column_name
    WHEN 'New data' THEN 1 
    WHEN 'open data' THEN 2 
    WHEN 'pending data' THEN 3 
END";
return new CActiveDataProvider ($this, array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria, //ordered criteria sent to CGridView
));
```

PS. tested under mysql - it works :)

Comment: Thank you very much. This will help me alot. ill put it in and edit and post the result . Thank you good sir

Comment: PS. I noticed ;) . Good Sir I thank YOU and I just want to say that you have saved my ass today. CHEERS !!

Comment: hehe :) good to know :). Mark my answer as 'accepted' if it really helps You:)